# Ruby Multiple OR Evaluations For String Value

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I was wondering if there was a dry way of writing the following in Ruby:

```
ext == ".xlsx" || ext == ".xls" || ext == ".ods"
```

My initial thought was the following which doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
ext == ".xlsx" || ".xls" || ".ods"
```

Comment: Your expectation for the second block of code is wrong.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yeah I noticed, hence the question.

Comment: Just making sure that you know it's not a bug in the ruby interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%w(.xlsx .xls .ods).include? ext
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is...

```
['.xlsx','.xls','.ods'].include? ext
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ext =~ /(.xlsx$)|(.xls$)|(.ods$)/

irb(main):009:0> '.xlsx' =~ /(.xlsx$)|(.xls$)|(.ods$)/
=> 0
irb(main):010:0> '.xlsa' =~ /(.xlsx$)|(.xls$)|(.ods$)/
=> nil
```