# Ruby Multiple AND Evaluations For Integer Value

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have, on a few occasions, found myself needing to write a rather verbose if statement in some ruby scripts.

The statement would look something like this:

```
if long_var_name == 0 && very_different_name == 0 && other_third_var == 0 && additional_variable == 0 && name_five == 0 && longest_variable_name_six == 0
  # (possibly even more conditions) 
  # do stuff here...
end
```

It seems like there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

The problem is, `if` and `and` aren't exactly easy to research with google, as basic english words. So I've come up empty-handed.

Does anyone know a way to shorten this kind of situation?
It can become a nightmare to read when you have even more of them.

- Sometimes variable renaming isn't an option.
- The names are sometimes vastly different.

Note: I found a clever solution for similar situations with OR:

[Ruby Multiple OR Evaluations For String Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12921940/2225842)

Comment: Not a bad question IMHO. Upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to sound whiny, but I've seen too many of other people's good questions get downvoted - I think those of us who try to answer a lot forget to upvote when we would have. (I'm sure I'm guilty, too) (and there are always sharks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an array and are specifically testing for zero, you can do:

```
vars1 = [0,0,3,0,0]
vars2 = [0,0,0,0,0]

vars1.all?(&:zero?) # false
vars2.all?(&:zero?) # true
```

EDIT: Based on OP's added conditions of having different names for the values:

```
if [long_var_name_1,long_var_name_2,long_var_name_3].all?(&:zero?)
  # do stuff here...
end
```

Comment: It's not inherently different from similar answers, but I like passing a `Proc` to `all?`! Upvote.

Comment: Very clean, and straight to the point. Thank you from me and the uppers.

Comment: Excellent improvement to the answer, too - though I assumed that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, I would write

```
if [a, b, c, d, e, f].all? { |var| var == 0 }
```

There's noting wrong about chaining `and` conditions IMHO.

Comment: There's not a serious problem with `and`. I just don't care for how messy it can get. I once had one three lines long.

Comment: Having unusually many conditions may be a sign that you need to refactor your code.

Comment: Sometimes it's code I don't have permission to refactor, but that's a great point. I'd considered writing a wrapper in some cases since it was all I could think of - to make it cleaner on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of breaking it up into logic expressions? Basically break it up into smaller bits of logical groupings and its easier to read e.g.

```
grp_1_zero = var_1 == 0 && var_2 == 0 && var_3 == 0
grp_2_zero = var_a == 0 && var_b == 0 && var_c == 0
grp_3_zero = var_z == 0 && var_x == 0 && var_y == 0

if grp_1_zero && grp_2_zero && grp_3_zero
  #code here
end
```

Comment: That's definitely worth consideration too. I might need this at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Another, for array `a`:

```
a == Array.new(a.size,0)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to instantiate a whole other array, but yes. You should edit this post to include the fact that this allows other possibilities. +upvote!

Comment: I'm not advocating this, just thought it was worth a mention.  `all? zero?` is clearly is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable#all?` and the `Symbol#to_proc` utilisation of the `Fixnum#zero?` method.

```
foo = 0
bar = 0
baz = 0

[foo, bar, baz].all? &:zero?
# => true

one = 1
two = 2

[foo, one, two].any? &:zero?
#=> true
```

Note that you can also provide any anonymous function for the test.

```
 owns_peanuts = ->(person){ person.inventory.contains :peanuts }
 [bill, david, mike].any? &owns_peanuts
```

Comment: Arguably the answer is useless without mentioning which methods are actually being called though, as it would just appear as Ruby magic. Each to their own though :-)